# Error "Failed to connect database" on some computers with RadBuilder application

Tags: dataset, firebird, radbuilder

I am facing problems with the application created with RadBuilder with Firebird Database. The problem is when I publish the project: it works on some computers, but on others it gives me this error:

> Failed to connect database "Database1"

Once I click on Login it shows this error:

> Cannot Perform this operation on a closed dataset

- Application works on Computer A (where I created this application in
  both run and even after I publish and try works perfectly)
- Computer B (working normally as a published application)
- Computer C Laptop (working normally as a published application )
- Computer D and so on i see get this error:

  > Failed to connect database "Database1"

Comment: Have you checked whether Computer D has access to the Database?

Comment: Yes i have checked Computer D. ODBC connection to database shows connection successful.